# string index not getting updated in a loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop, enumerate

I am parsing a string for spaces and i find that the string index is not getting updated even after updating the string, where am i wrong ? will be very happy for any guidance provided

````
class Palindrome:
    
    def __init__(self,seq):
        self.seq=seq.lower()
        
    def remove_space(self):
        print('up',self.seq)
        for num,i in enumerate(self.seq):
            print('start',self.seq)
            if i==' ':
                print('orig',(num,i))
                new_seq=self.seq[:num]+self.seq[num+1:]  
                num=num+1
                self.seq=new_seq # updating the string here
                print('now',self.seq)
                print(num)
        #print(new_seq)        
seq1=Palindrome('superman is here')           
seq1.remove_space() ```
````

Comment: What doesn't work, can you share the expected results

Comment: You should not be changing the value of `num` or `self.seq`, or even `i` inside your loop.  It probably won't result in what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to proceed with your method, you need to account for the number of spaces you've already removed from the string. And I also included an alternative way of removing space while still using a loop.

```
class Palindrome:
    
    def __init__(self,seq):
        self.seq=seq.lower()
        
    def remove_space_alt(self):
        print(self.seq)
        temp_string = ''
        for i, letter in enumerate(self.seq):
            if letter != ' ':
                temp_string += letter
        self.seq = temp_string
        print(self.seq)
        
    def remove_space(self):
        print(self.seq)
        space_count = 0
        for i, letter in enumerate(self.seq):
            if letter == ' ':
                first = self.seq[:i - space_count]
                second = self.seq[i + 1 - space_count:]
                space_count += 1
                self.seq = first + second
                print(self.seq)


print('Showing remove_space')       
seq1=Palindrome('superman is here')
seq1.remove_space()

print('\nShowing remove_space_alt')
seq1=Palindrome('superman is here')
seq1.remove_space_alt()
```

Output:

```
Showing remove_space
superman is here
supermanis here
supermanishere

Showing remove_space_alt
superman is here
supermanishere
```

Original Post: Suggested using string replace() to remove spaces, and did not fully explain issue with changing for-loop index mid loop.

Comment: I agree there are better ways, just i needed to know why the index is not getting updated